# Matrices in $\,\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ having only zero as eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Does there exist a matrix $A$ in $\Bbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ that has only $0$ as eigenvalue?

As far as I think, an upper diagonal matrix with only zeros on the diagonal is such an example.

And if I'm correct, is such a matrix diagonalizable?

Comment: The zero matrix $O$ is diagonalizable, for example as $O=IOI^{-1}$, noting that to be a diagonal matrix, one only requires that any nonzero entries (*if they exist at all*) would need to lie along the diagonal.  Not having any nonzero entries does not prevent a matrix from being a diagonal matrix.

Comment: This is one way to get such matrices, yes. If it were diagonalizable, wouldn't that say it had to be the $0$ matrix? By the way, here's a $2\times 2$ example you should understand: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct: by taking $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ you have $sp(A)=\{0\}$.
Anyway it isn’t diagonalizable, it is already in Jordan canonical form.

In general if $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ so that $B$ has only eigen-value $0$ ($sp(B)=\{0\}$) then $B$ is diagonalizable $\iff B=0$ (denoting with $q_B$ the minimal polinomial of $B$): $B$ is diagonalizable $\iff q_B$ is product of linear coprime factors, and because $B$ has only $0$ as eigen-value it must be $q_B(t)=t\iff B=0$.

Comment: More generally, if a diagonalizable order-$n$ matrix has only one eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $n$, it must be a multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 0):

You're right with your thinking: an upper-triangular matrix with only zeros on the diagonal has $0$ as the only eigenvalue, for example, the zero matrix. Your second statement is incorrect; consider the matrix
\begin{align}
A&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
This matrix has $0$ as the only eigenvalue, however, it is not diagonalizable. One way to see this is to notice that $A$ is already a Jordan matrix, but not all the Jordan blocks are $1 \times 1$.

Alternatively, it's easy to verify that $\ker(A)$ (which is the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$) is $2$-dimensional, and in fact $\{e_1, e_3\}$ is a basis for $\ker(A)$. i.e we only have $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$, whereas for $A$ to be diagonalizable, we need $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors.